# What exactly is GCC's auto-vectorized SSE2 implementation of sum += 1..n doing?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization, sse

When GCC 8.3 for x86-64 with `-O3` option is fed this small C function

```
int sum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

it produces the following assembly (courtesy of [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cVp1hR)):

```
sum:
  test edi, edi
  jle .L8
  lea eax, [rdi-1]
  cmp eax, 17
  jbe .L9
  mov edx, edi
  movdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
  xor eax, eax
  pxor xmm0, xmm0
  movdqa xmm2, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
  shr edx, 2
.L4:
  add eax, 1
  paddd xmm0, xmm1
  paddd xmm1, xmm2
  cmp eax, edx
  jne .L4
  movdqa xmm1, xmm0
  mov ecx, edi
  psrldq xmm1, 8
  and ecx, -4
  paddd xmm0, xmm1
  lea edx, [rcx+1]
  movdqa xmm1, xmm0
  psrldq xmm1, 4
  paddd xmm0, xmm1
  movd eax, xmm0
  cmp edi, ecx
  je .L13
.L7:
  add eax, edx
  add edx, 1
  cmp edi, edx
  jge .L7
  ret
.L13:
  ret
.L8:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
.L9:
  mov edx, 1
  xor eax, eax
  jmp .L7
.LC0:
  .long 1
  .long 2
  .long 3
  .long 4
.LC1:
  .long 4
  .long 4
  .long 4
  .long 4
```

I understand that for values of `n` less than 19, a completely unoptmized loop (code at `.L9` and `.L7`) is used, but I can't make heads nor tails of what is happening for larger values of `n` — could someone explain it?

Clang, on the other hand, simply calculates `(n-1)*(n-2)/2 + 2*n - 1`, which is a slighlty more roundabout way of calculating `n*(n+1)/2` — perhaps to prevent some problems with signed overflow — which seems to be a much more effective way to optimize this loop.

Comment: It got vectorized to calculate 4 partial sums in parallel.

Comment: @Jester The vectorized loop adds fours to fours repeatedly, then throws half of the results away, then... does something weird again, and finally, the last summands are added in with the unoptimized loop. I don't understand how exactly that achieves anything.

Comment: The 4 is the increment of the loop since it does 4 items in parallel. Notice that xmm1 is updated, that is your vectorized `i`. Originally you had `i++` but that's now `i += 4`.  The vectorized `i` starts out as `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` then becomes `{5, 6, 7, 8}` by adding `{ 4, 4, 4, 4}` and so on. The code block before `.L7` adds the four partial sums together horizontally. Finally the remaining numbers are added, if `n` is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: The stuff after `jne .L4` is a horizontal sum of `xmm0`,  interleaved with calculating how many iterations are left-over after the 4-at-a-time loop.  (The horizontal sum is done with movdqa + in-place byte shift, instead of efficient `pshufd` copy-and-shuffle.  Mentioned in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80846 along with AVX2 sillyness.  See also [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/6996764))

Comment: Anyway, I highly recommend single-stepping through this in a debugger and watching register values change.  e.g. in GDB: `display  $xmm0.v4_int32` and single-step instructions with `si`.

Comment: what I find most astonishing is that CLANG is recognizing it can use Gauß' sum formular. respect !